# How to initialize all classes at the same time

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, bukkit

In my Java plugin for Bukkit, It is my first time that I separate my code to Service Providers so I can easily disable a part of it when I am debugging.

That caused for some reason an unexpected problem in which I get **NullPointerExceptions** from services that have initialized, but they include code from other services which they haven't yet.

For example:

```
worldServiceProvider = new WorldServiceProvider();
clientServiceProvider = new ClientServiceProvider();
menuServiceProvider = new MenuServiceProvider();
statsServiceProvider = new StatsServiceProvider();
commandServiceProvider = new CommandServiceProvider();
battleServiceProvider = new BattleServiceProvider();
serverServiceProvider = new ServerServiceProvider();
```

That structure always causes errors. How do I solve that initialization problem, or what should I change in my design?

In case you want to check out the source code, here is my github.

https://github.com/parat26/ares-network/tree/master/src/src/ares/core

Comment: I think you need to figure out what order you think they should be initialised in and change your constructor code to make it work. Circular dependencies are a problem.

Comment: What happens if that works like a chain? This will be initialized when the server is boot up. Doesn't that mean each one of them would be instantiated practically at the same time?

Comment: _Practically_ the same time isn't a problem unless you're initialising them in separate threads (in which case, don't do that).

Comment: Assuming that the code is being run in the same plugin, they are not separated threads. But how come they return null values while they instantiate at the same time?

Comment: You can't. There's never a need to. The fact that NPEs are thrown on initialization means your classes has an incorrect circular dependency and constructors fail to complete construction without throwing the NPE. Fix those instead. This question cannot be answered in its current state and I've voted to close it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this would be to use an order in which you initialize these variables. Initialize that one first which don't depend on any other, and then second and so on.

NullPointerException means that the object doesn't exist until now, so, creating it will minimize this problem, create those in an order.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have what is called a coupling problem. Basically, 2 or more systems that are not supposed to know about each other do know each other. The best thing you could try to do now (hopefully you don't have too large of a code base) is decouple your providers so that they don't know about each other and you can disable them at will.

The other method you could try (which is really bad programming practice talking from my experience) is instead of accessing providers directly, use if statement to check if they aren't null and only then do your logic.

```
// instead of this:
float defaultGravity = Providers.physicsProvider.getDefaultGravity();

// do something like this:
float defaultGravity = 9.8f; // some magic default number in case provider is not found
if (Providers.physicsProdiver != null) {
    defaultGravity = Providers.physicsProvider.getDefaultGravity();
}
```

Again, I think this is really bad design and should only be used as a last resort and only in few places in code. You don't want your code checking for nulls where the values are not supposed to be null by design to begin with.

This is a very good free online book about programming patterns. It is long, but anyone who hasn't read it will probably learn something. 
http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/contents.html

Comment: That sounds like a plan, however before I even change to Service Providers, everything worked perfectly, I used Managers which made code really messy and big. I don't get it why this is not the same as before.

Comment: But why would you disable providers? As you can see, that doesn't help you at all. The whole design point of providers is that they are always there.